# How to prevent Visual Studio from formatting <% %> on two lines?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010

The question is [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895790/why-does-visual-studios-format-document-tool-put-heading-tags-over-two-lines), but I cannot figure how to make the formatting also apply to the ASP.NET server side tag `<% %>`

Like the related question, a block like this one

**Good**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
</ul>
```

Will get formatted into

**Bad**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
    <li>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
</ul>
```

I want to prevent Visual Studio from changing the formatting concerning asp.net server tag `<% %>`.

Does someone know?

Nota: This is not a question about minifying the html output. This is for design time only. Its more of an annoyance than anything else.

Comment: Hmm, the second looks uglier and eats additional bytes of bandwidth. You can't say whether/where those `<li>`s are closed.

Comment: Exactly, he wants to know how to avoid it formatting like the second.

Comment: um....this problem also happen on webforms....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Tools -> Options -> Tree View Text Editor node -> HTML -> Format -> Tag Specific Options button -> Default Settings -> Client tag does not support contents ->
In the Line breaks dropdown, select None.

The <% ... %> is seen by the editor as just another tag, in this case a Client tag that doesn't support contents.

Comment: The `li` setting is already at Before and After. It work well if the content is not a `<% %>`. As soon as I embed code in my page, the format setting for all elements fails.

Comment: Figured it out, the tag is `%:` and not a single `%`.